# C# .NET 5.0 - Formatter of the sign of negative decimals sometimes prints a plus

Tags: c#, .net, c#-9.0

Consider this code:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"{-0.4m:+;-;+}");
Console.WriteLine($"{-0.5m:+;-;+}");
```

It prints

```
+
-
```

Is this a .NET bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's due to rounding according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--section-separator):

> If the number to be formatted is nonzero, but becomes zero after rounding according to the format in the first or second section, the resulting zero is formatted according to the third section.